# node.override attribute in chef recipe resource gets set but not getting used

Tags: chef-infra

I have a custom resource in my recipe that overrides a node attribute. When I use that node attribute in a later resource section of the same recipe, it is using the default attribute set in the cookbook attributes file instead of the value set in the custom recipe resource. After the chef-client run, the attribute value on the node is showing the expected overriden value. What is causing the recipe not to use the overriden attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are trying to override `node['something']['content']` and your recipe looks like:

```
my_resource 'a name' do
  action :run
end

file '/tmp/file' do
  content node['something']['content']
end
```

The code defined in the `:run` action of your custom resource is executed at convergence time whereas the attribute `node['something']['content']` used in the file resource is read at compilation time.

For reference, a chef-client run can be described as:

- library loading
- attribute compilation (this is where the default value of your attribute is set)
- recipe compilation (this is where your my_resource and file resources are built with their parameters)
- resource convergence (this is where the `:run` action code is executed and where your attribute is overriden).
- reporting (this is where your overriden attribute value is sent to the chef server).

Comment: This explains the behavior I am seeing perfectly - thanks! What I did was included the logic to override the node attribute in a recipe instead of a resource and included that recipe in the default recipe that needs the new value and this seems to work better.